# Parse whereEqualsTo not working in android

Tags: android, parsing

I'm trying to use Parse in a personal project but I faced a problem when I tried to get data from a new object called "Image". What I'm trying to do is from a list of users select one and display all the images related to the selected user, If I remove the `whereEqualsTo` I receive the images related to the user I'm login in. If I put `whereEqualsTo` I receive nothing.

This is my code:

```
private void getUserImages(final String selectedUserName) {

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Image");

    query.whereEqualTo("username", selectedUserName);

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                if (objects.size() > 0){
                    //Do something
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is my config class:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .applicationId("202ac01cxxxxxxxxxxa41d1136bc8a86213328b4")
            .clientKey("76b883b596xxxxxxxxxf60f9352fdb926dde46e")
            .server("http://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-59.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:80/parse/")
    .build());

    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
}
```

[image]

Someone has any idea, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ParseUser class is secured by default. Data stored in a ParseUser can only be modified by that user. By default, the data can still be read by any client. Thus, some ParseUser objects are authenticated and can be modified, whereas others are read-only.

For any object, you can specify which users are allowed to read the object, and which users are allowed to modify an object. To support this type of security, each object has an access control list, implemented by the ParseACL class.

See this documentation on how to set Access Control list and give specific permissions.[Parse User documentation](http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#users)

Comment: Than you @random, I already check the documentation but I'll do again, maybe I miss something.